# Possible null reference return in EntityTypeBuilder.HasOne.WithOne

Tags: c#, entity-framework, foreign-keys, nullable-reference-types

I am going through code that predates my involvement with my project, cleaning up null reference issues with Nullable annotations and warnings enabled.

In one spot, we have a self-referential entity type that may or may not have parents and children of the same type; the associated properties have obviously been set to nullable.

The compiler warning `Possible null reference return` comes into play on defining either the parent or the child references:

```
entity.HasOne(d => d.Parent)
  .WithOne(p => p.Child)
```

`Child` gets marked with the `Possible null reference return` warning (and `p` gets dinged for with a `Dereference of a possibly null reference` while we're at it).

I know I can get hide the warning with `p.Child!` (and `(p == null ? null : p.Child)!` takes care of the dereference), but this feels somewhat off to me. I worry about it causing Linq problems or some other issue that I might not think to look for until it breaks somewhere down the line.

Is there a better or preferred way to handle this, or will the ternary approach be fine?

Answer (score 1):

According to the Entity Framework [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/miscellaneous/nullable-reference-types#navigating-and-including-nullable-relationships), the preferred way to handle this is to either move the first `!` up to the `.Has` function:

```
entity.HasOne(d => d.Parent!)
  .WithOne(p => p.Child!)
```

or to make the property non-nullable and configure it as optional via the Fluent API or Data Annotations:

```
class Child
{
  [Optional]        // <--- Either this way
  public virtual Parent Parent { get; set; } // No "!"
}
```

```
entity.HasOne(d => d.Parent)
  .WithOne(p => p.Child)     // Likewise for the Child within the Parent
  .IsRequired(false)    // <--- Or this way
```

Marking the property with `!` in the `.Has` function is safer if the properties are frequently accessed in your own code, while relying on the configuration to express optionality may be more concise if the properties are primarily used within EF Core queries.